# Parametric Curves - Tangent to the curve

Tags: calculus, curves, parametric, tangent-line

I am struggling with finding the tangents to a curve below that passes through point (12,9).
$$x=9t^2 +3 ,\qquad y=6t^3 +3$$

I have $dx/dt= 18t,\enspace  dy/dt=18t^2$, which then gives us $0= -3t^2+15t-6$
Now, I think this is where my problem is coming in:
I pulled out -3 to get $0= -3(t^2-5t+2)$ which is not easily/rationally factorable.

So the equations I came up with (there should be 2) are:
$y=x-21$ and $y=-2x+24$

Can anyone point me in the correct direction/assist me in determining the answers.

Comment: How did you get $0= -3t^2+15t-6$? One solution for the curve passing through $(12,9)$ is $t=1$, so I think you did something wrong trying to solve for $t$.

Comment: I utilized point slope form so y-y1=m(x-x1) and solved to make one side 0. I attempted to factor from there.

Comment: I'm not sure why you did that. The solutions to $y-12=m(x-9)$ are the points on a straight line with slope $m$ through $(9,12)$. You don't know what $m$ is until you find the $t$ value(s) where the curve passes through $(9,12)$. What did you use for $m$? The first thing you need to do is find the $t$ value(s) where the curve passes through $(9,12)$.

Comment: I was following an example from class.  I used t for m. So I see that if we plug in the points provided we do get t=1 as one solution. Would we obtain the other solution by solving for zero (I got t=1/8 (from x equation) & t=1/9 (from y equation) for this)

Comment: The way you get $t=1$ is by finding out what $t$ value(s) give(s) you $x=12$ and $y=9$. It has to be the same $t$-value that gives you $x=12$ and $y=9$, or the parametric curve doesn't pass through the point $(12,9)$ at one $t$-value. In other words, you solve the equations $x=9t^2+3=12; y=6t^3+3=9$. It looks like there is only one solution, $t=1$. What about the question makes you think there is more than one tangent to the curve at that point. (Huge suggestion: Sketch the curve!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Since the point (12,9) is on the curve, we can determine that $t=1$. Calculate the slope of this point,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}= \frac{18t^2}{18t} = 1$$

Then, use the point-slope equation to obtain the tangent line $y-9=x-12$, or,

$$y = x -3$$

Comment: Thank you very much.